# ScrollView over ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've got a horizontal scroll view (red part in pic) and a vertical on (blue part in pic)

When u scroll vertically the blue will go over the red. The red holds images where u can swipe horizontally. When I make the blue scroll view big enough so that the items in it will scroll to the top of the screen, the red ScrollView doesn't detect swipes as its underneath the blue ScrollView

How can I make the red (horizontal) ScrollView work as well?.
Image of actual UI - https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bcphjl6ncv2olu/Photo%202017-04-15%2C%2012%2030%2007%20AM.jpg?dl=0

[Image being referred to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbVM1.png)

Comment: You need to try and clarify what you're asking... Based on the image - and the image you posted in a comment below - it's still not clear what you're trying to do. Perhaps show an image of how you want it to look when Blue is covering Red? How can the user know what he is swiping, if it is completely covered? Is there some transparent area?

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to an image of my actual UI which should clear things up a bit better @DonMag

Comment: Yes, I saw that in your comment below... but in that image, nothing is covering the "Red" area. Show an image of how it will look when "Blue" is scrolled to the top, and you still want the user to be able to swipe the image in "Red"

Comment: The red and blue are just representing scroll views, they aren't actually red and blue in the app. In the UI the image is in the horizontal  scroll view (represented in red) and the card is the vertical scroll view represented in blue @DonMag

Comment: Yes, understood... easier to refer to them as "Red" and "Blue"... in the image you show, "Blue" is ***not*** covering "Red" ... so, how will your interface look when it ***is*** covering it?

Comment: The whole card will slide up over the image (referring to the actual UI pic). The issue I'm having is that this scroll view covers the other scroll view (the scroll view not the content in the ScrollView) so now the user can't interact with the image scroll view as it is behind @DonMag

Comment: oookaaaayy... and that's the confusing part... if the Content scrolls up and covers the image, how can the user see the image to interact with it?

Comment: No no, the content covering the image is intended. I'm saying when it's not covering the image the ScrollView still covers the image scroll view. So when you swipe in that area it doesn't do anything. If you move the image scroll view to the front. Then it works but now the content from the bottom ScrollView goes under the image which isn't how it should be @DonMag

Comment: Ah... now I understand... search for `UITableView Header parallax`. While you're not describing implementing a parallax effect on the image portion, seeing how that is done will probably put you on the right track. (this is just one example of how it looks if that doesn't sound familiar to you ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jv2z_qMD_2U)

Comment: That's actually exactly something I was going to add later on, but I've got multiple images to be displayed there for the user to swipe through. Any ideas what I can do? @DonMag

Comment: Or maybe I could do what's in the video, change the image every couple secs and when the user taps on the image, it goes to a separate viewController to view images in full screen and swipe between them (like the photos app) @DonMag

Comment: I did some playing around and added an answer you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nolan - now that I understand what you're going for, there may be a pretty straight-forward way to do it.

If you subclass `UIScrollView`, you can "intercept" touches and either allow them to behave normally, or pass them through to other views. Here's a very simplistic example:

```
class PassThruScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        if point.y < 200 {
            return false
        }       
        return true
    }       
}
```

I put together a working example if you'd like to see it: https://github.com/DonMag/ScrollViewPassThru

Comment: Thanks!! Thats exactly what I was trying to do and the sample project helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what do you want. maybe you want the blue one underneath of the red one, and when you scroll up the blue one, it doesn't cover the red one, right?

if that's the case, you probably need to take a look at your layout again on these two components. you can either set the top constrain of the blue scrollview align with the bottom of the red one. Or you can just set the hierarchy of blue scrollview below the red scrollview.
hopefully it can be help.

Comment: No not exactly. When u scroll up with the blue one it covers the red one. But the problem I'm having is that in the interface builder the blue scroll view covers the red and then the user can use the red scroll view. (I've updated the question to make it clearer)

Comment: @NolanRanolin if the blue one covers the red one, you can't even see it, how could you expect user still able to interact with the red scrollview?

Comment: Here's a pic of my interface, you might understand better if u see it https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bcphjl6ncv2olu/Photo%202017-04-15%2C%2012%2030%2007%20AM.jpg?dl=0